# Django templates and JSON response

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using Django to create Website. In order to use json in html, I send json in views.

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
 def json_data(request):
     data = words.objects.all()
     return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

**models.py**

```
class words(models.Model):
   word = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   value = models.FloatField(default=0)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.word
```

And I want to parse json and use it in this form.

**result.html**

```
items: [
    {text: "Java", count: "236"},
    {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
    {text: "Php", count: "170"},
    {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
    {text: "D", count: "12"},
    {text: "Python", count: "170"},
    {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
    {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
    {text: "Something", count: "170"},
  ],
```

I do not know how to code JS. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX call in order to get the data asynchronouly like the following.

Try this

```
def view_name(request):
    html = '<div>Hello World</div>'
    return JsonResponse({"data": html, "message": "your message"})
```

In html

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/view/',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
             console.log(response.message);
             $('#test').append(response.data);
       }
    });
});
</script>
```